# Adding 20 amp line to exterior breaker box using junction box

Tags: electrical

I need to add a 20 amp circuit, but the breaker box is outside and routing 12 awg down or through wall into breaker box is not possible. I’m aware that I will need to transition from THHN to romex, when going from outside conduit (THHN) to attic (romex) via a junction box. The question is, can this junction box sit underneath soffit, or does it need to be inside attic?  The only knockouts are on the bottom so I’d somehow have to route the emt from underneath, to soffit. A waterproof junction box at the soffit will be easier to service, but only if this is allowed.

[image]

Comment: Would it be easier to just run EMT the entire way? I'm conduit guy.

Comment: @JACK Good suggestion.  I will still have to transition from THHN to romex at some point. I have a 20’ run, so unless I have 20’+ of 12 AWG THHN (which I don’t), I’ll still need to transition to regular 12 AWG romex, that feeds the circuit. To my understanding, I cannot run romex in conduit, when it exits the house and into exterior breaker box, as much as I want to being such a short distance. Just looking for all possibilities. Thank you.

Comment: Check with your local inspector, he allowed me to do it and I simply had to stub the condulet into the house with a bushing. I used an LB to make the 90. In total it was about 3' of condulet. I did this about 10 years ago and no problems.

Comment: If you run EMT from your panel up into the attic and put a junction box just inside the attic, you could make your transition to Romex in that without having to worry about weatherproof boxes and fittings.

Comment: You're planning all this work and unwilling to buy 20 feet of THHN?  I'm confused.

Comment: @Gil I’ll look into this.

Comment: @Armand that was my initial thinking and my go this route.

Comment: @Robert Chapin I made a mistake in my description and meant to say a 60’ run, and before I knew I possibly could not go outside with NM romex, I had already bought and unpackaged the romex, and partially snaked it through the start of the new circuit run.

Comment: At least that's a relatively cheap mistake. Undo your work, do it the right way, take the loss on materials. It's how you pay for your learning as a DIYer.

Comment: An added bonus to what @KMJ said is that you've still got all the NM to use in the future.